# 2 types of Video Card

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda, nouveau

I have a setup where I have 2 `NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]` and a `NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210]` .
I have the monitors plugged into the `210` and want to use the 2x `970`s for GPU programming (`CUDA`) etc.

1) Is it possible to have 2 different types of NVidia Graphics Card running at the same time?

2) Is it possible to use the Nouveau driver for display (which works OOTB) and install a `CUDA` driver for the "non-display" cards?

3) If I don't want to use Graphics Drivers for the `970`s what is the minimum I need to install for running `CUDA`?

I want a minimum install, as the last time I tried to update `ubuntu` I lost 4 days needing to rebuild everything from scratch, as I couldn't boot.

Running 16.04 LTS, brand new installation, nothing updated.
FYI, apparently updating ubuntu causes my machine to not boot, so I would like to avoid `apt-get update` until I get my setup working.

Comment: I have tried :

the run file from nvidia: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
installing from apt: `sudo apt-get install cuda`

and on different occasions installing `nvidia-340`, `nvidia-304`, `nvidia-367`, `nvidia-370` ...
None of these, or combinations of these worked, and I ended up with an unbootable system on numerous occasions. I'd like to avoid that again.


Has anyone tried or had success with http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/106780/en-us?

Answer (score 0):

On complete reinstall and then installing the NVidia driver, it appears that I can't have these specific graphics cards working together.

I have removed the `GeForce 210` and just used the 2 `GeForce 970`.

Also, of super important note: for these I specifically ***could not use*** linux kernel 4.4 and on upgrading to the latest 4.7.5 and reinstalling the drivers from NVidia this worked fine.

NVidia: `Driver Version: 367.44`

Linux: `4.7.5-040705-generic`